# Inject a function into a command of a viewmodel via IoC

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control

**Application Design**

The application is a windows containing x tabs. Each tab has a view which include another view called 'LiveComment'.

Description :

*MainWindowLogic* : Responsible to hold all the data logic. A function AddComment(String comment, DateTime time, String NameOfTheTab) is written via an interface (let's say IAddComment). This logic is accessible via an IoC container : IoC.Current return the instance of MainWindowLogic.

*MainWindowViewModel* : Hold all the views, nothing special

*TabViewModel* : Contains a 'LiveCommentView' and a string NameOfTheTab

*LiveCommentViewModel* : Contains a String comment, a DateTime time and a ICommand Send. The Send command is used to push the comment and time into the logic.

**Logic**

When a user is in a tab and push the send button of the LiveComment, the logic must be called with the time and comment from the LiveComment and the NameOfTheTab where the LiveComment is.

**Question**

As I want to use the MVVM pattern, all my views should be able to get the current application logic via the IoC (IoC.Current). And then in each 'LiveCommentViewModel' I'm able to access the AddComment method from the MainWindowLogic. The problem is that the AddComment need 3 parameters and the 'LiveCommentViewModel' has only 2 of them. The last one is found into the 'TabViewModel' (the name of the tab).

How can I access the name of the tab ? Because of MVVM the 'LiveCommentViewModel' is not aware of the 'TabViewModel' (and then the nameOfTab).

For now, the solution I have is to create a constructor with a parameter :

```
    public LiveCommentViewModel(Action<String,DateTime> Send)
    {
        SendCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { SendMethod(Send); });
    }
```

The Action send is then initialised into the TabViewModel (doing that, I remove the power of the IoC...)

```
CommentBox = new LiveCommentViewModel((comment,TimeOfComment) => { SendCommentFunction(comment, TimeOfComment, Name); });
```

And then the 'SendCommentFunction' can be found into the IoC

If not clear enough, just tell me.

**EDIT**

I've represented an image of what I currently have. Which shows that my MainWindowViewModel creates and push everything into a IoC.
When my view is loaded, every TabViewModel or LiveCommentViewModel are trying to get their respective DataContext by calling the IoC (which is MVVM if I well understand)

Because of that, I've a limitation. When the send command is called by the user I want to use the "AddComment" from the MainWindowViewModel but it requires the NameOfTheTab that I don't have.
[image]

The solution of @Andy means that I've to inject the ICommand function inside the LiveCommentViewModel when creating it inside the MainWindowViewModel which will of course work (thank you for that). But is it a good way to do it ?

Comment: I don't think your description is clear enough. You've included a stack of description of things are very tightly related to the code you have but I don't follow what your issue is. In the title you ask about a function. In your description you ask about a string. Which is your issue? One answer might be not to rely on a string for which tab and to handle the command in the tab vm itself. Put the different logic in each tab viewmodel  so it has whichever logic it needs to use.

Comment: I edit my post in the hope it's more clear. If always not I will make a little git project
Thank you for your time